# how would an android app communicate with a node.js + redis + socket.io rails backend?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, node.js, redis, backend

how would an android app communicate with a node.js + redis + socket.io rails backend for a chat application? would I just send requests to the rails server since it pushes/receives to the node server through redis?

Comment: How did a rails server get involved?

Comment: Well I was making the backend for a chat app in rails then I was informed that a websocket connection will take up too much memory so I'm trying to use redis to connect to a node.js to handle just the websocket connection.